# Menu bar application actions with Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've recently been trying to create an application on Xcode 9.4.1 with the Objective-C programming language.

I am trying to make the application work from the menu bar rather than a full app.

However, I have only managed to make the Menu items show up and have no idea how to add actions such as a web link to the buttons.

Can anyone help with this? All I want is to add actions to the buttons using code.

P.S. I am not using storyboards.

Comment: *No storyboard* means no Interface Builder at all? And show the relevant code you have so far.

Comment: Do you mean a macos app? If so, add the relevant tag because what you've written doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Without providing what you've done so far it seems like you're asking for complete code, nevertheless I happen to have an old project that does it. In the app delegate you do something like this: in the barItemAction method you can do whatever you need to perform

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property NSStatusItem *barItem ;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.barItem = [NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    self.barItem.button.title = @"";
    [self.barItem setAction:@selector(barItemAction)];
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

-(void)barItemAction {
    NSLog(@" button was clicked ");
}
```